# How to print a numpy array with data type?

Tags: python, numpy

When I run following code using a script I get,

```
a = np.arange(4, dtype=object).reshape((2,2))
print(a[:,0]);
```

Result: [0, 2].

But if I run the following code in terminal, I get,

```
a = np.arange(4, dtype=object).reshape((2,2))
a[:,0]
```

Result: array([0, 2], dtype=object)

How can I get the 2nd output using print method in a script file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` defaults to printing the `str` representation of its arguments. You need the `repr` representation:

```
print(repr(a[:, 0]))
```